# How to split the specified part of a file that has no delimiter using plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a development in which I insert a log file in a table.
The file I insert is something similar to this:

```
***ORACLE COA MX                                      Journal Import Execution Report                              Date: 2022-10-11 14:23
Process ID: 890555.                                                                                            Page:               1
                                                          Total   Total   Total Unbalanced Unbalanced       Flex    Nonflex
Journal Entry Source Name    Group ID           Status    Lines Batches Headers    Batches    Headers     Errors     Errors
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Manual                                    90005 Error         1       1       1          1          1          0          0
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       *** TOTALS ***                                         1       1       1          1          1          0          0
 
=======================================================   Batches Created   ========================================================
 
 
                                                                               Total   Total               Total               Total
Warning Batch Name                                               Period Name   Lines Headers    Accounted Debits   Accounted Credits
------- ------------------------------------- ---------- ------- ------- ---------------- ----------------
 
=================================================   Unbalanced Journal Entries**   =================================================
 
 
Error                                                                            Total
Code  Journal Entry Name                    Batch Name                           Lines Period Name    Total Debits    Total Credits
----- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ----- ----------- ---------------- ----------------
EU02   Adjustment SEM980701STA             Importación de asientos SOAPUI 11102     1 Oct-22              1,300.00             0.00
 
=========================================================   Error Lines   ==========================================================
 
 
                                                              Accounting
Error Code                     Source                         Date        Currency      Entered Debit     Entered Credit Account        
------------------------------ ----------- ----------- -------- ---------------- ---------------- ------------------------
 
==========================================================   Error Key   ===========================================================
 
Period Error Codes
------------------
EP01   This date isn't in an open or future enterable period.
EP02   This ledger doesn't have an open or future enterable periods.
EP03   This date isn't within a period in an open encumbrance year.
EP04   This date isn't a business day.
EP05   There are no business days in this period.
Unbalanced Journal Error Codes
------------------------------
WU01   The journal entry is unbalanced. Suspense posting is allowed in this ledger and processed the entry.
EU02   The journal entry is unbalanced and suspense posting isn't allowed in the ledger.
EU03   The encumbrance journal entry is unbalanced and the Reserve for Encumbrance account isn't defined.
Flexfield Error Codes
---------------------
EF01   The account is inactive for the accounting date.
EF02   Detail posting isn't allowed for this account.
EF03   There are disabled accounts.
EF04   The account is invalid. Check your cross validation rules and segment values.
EF05   There is no account with this account combination ID.
EF06   The alternate account is invalid.
WF01   An alternate account was used instead of the original account.
WF02   A suspense account was used instead of the original account.

ORACLE COA MX                                      Journal Import Execution Report                              Date: 2022-10-11 14:23
Process ID: 890555.                                                                                            Page:               2
                                                                                                                                    
==========================================================   Error Key   ===========================================================
Foreign Currency Error Codes
----------------------------
EC01   A conversion rate must be entered with the User conversion rate type.
EC02   The conversion date is missing.
EC03   A conversion rate type or an accounted amount must be supplied when entering foreign currency journal lines.
EC06   There is no conversion rate for this currency, conversion rate type, and conversion date.
EC08   There are invalid currencies.
EC09   No currencies are enabled.
EC10   Encumbrance journals can't be created in a foreign currency.
EC11   Invalid conversion rate type.
EC12   The entered amount must equal the accounted amount in a ledger or statistical currency journal line.
EC13   Amount is too large.
ECW1   Converted amounts can't be validated because the conversion rate type isn't specified.
Encumbrance Error Codes.
-----------------------
EE01   An encumbrance type is required for encumbrance lines.
EE02   Invalid or disabled encumbrance type.
EE03   Encumbrance journals can't be created in the STAT currency.
EE04   The BUDGET_VERSION_ID column must be null for encumbrance lines.
EE05   Average journals can't be created for encumbrances.
EE06   Originating company information can't be specified for encumbrances.
EE07   Encumbrance accounting is not enabled
Reversal Error Codes
------------------
ER01   A reversal period name must be provided.
ER02   This reversal period name is invalid. Check your calendar for valid periods.
ER03   The reversal date must be provided
ER04   This reversal date isn't in a valid period.
ER05   This reversal date isn't in your database date format.
ER06   Your reversal date must be the same as or after your effective date.
ER07   This reversal date isn't a business day.
ER08   There are no business days in your reversal period.
ER09   Default reversal information couldn't be determined.
Descriptive Flexfield Error Codes
--------------------------------
ED01   The context and attribute values don't form a valid descriptive flexfield for Journals - Journal Entry Lines.
ED02   The context and attribute values don't form a valid descriptive flexfield for Journals - Captured Information.
ED03   The context and attribute values don't form a valid descriptive flexfield for Value Added Tax.
Miscellaneous Error Codes
--------------------------------
EM01   Invalid journal entry category.
EM02   There are no journal entry categories defined.
EM05   The ENCUMBRANCE_TYPE_ID column must be null for actual journals.
EM06   The BUDGET_VERSION_ID column must be null for actual journals.
EM07   The statistical amount belongs in the entered_dr or entered_cr column when entering a STAT currency journal line.
EM09   There is no transaction code defined.
EM10   There are invalid transaction codes.
EM12   An error occurred when generating sequential numbering.
EM13   The assigned sequence is inactive.
EM14   There is a sequential numbering setup error resulting from a missing grant or synonym.
EM17   Sequential numbering is always used and there is no assignment for this ledger and journal entry category.
EM18   Manual document sequences can't be used with Journal Import.
EM19   Value Added Tax data is only valid in conjunction with actual journals.
EM24   Average journals can only be imported into consolidation ledgers.
EM25   Invalid average journal column value. Valid values are {Y_CODE, {N_CODE, and null.

ORACLE COA MX                                      Journal Import Execution Report                              Date: 2022-10-11 14:23
Process ID: 890555.                                                                                            Page:               3
                                                                                                                                    
==========================================================   Error Key   ===========================================================
Miscellaneous Error Codes
--------------------------------
EM26   There are invalid originating companies.
EM27   Originating company information can only be specified when intercompany balancing is enabled.
EM29   You don't have access to this ledger and account combination.
EM30   This primary balancing segment value isn't valid for this ledger.
EM31   This management segment value isn't valid for this ledger.
EM32   The balancing segment value entered isn't valid for this legal entity.
EM33   The management segment value entered isn't valid for this legal entity.
EM34   The legal entity identifier must be populated because the ledger sequencing mode is set to legal entity.
EM35   The legal entity identifier must be NULL because the ledger sequencing mode isn't enabled.
Federal Financials Error Codes
--------------------------------
EG01   The GL journal import prevalidation process couldn't be validated. You must verify the ledger setup.
EG02   You must enter a valid Business Event Type Code.
EG03   The BETC value can't be derived. You must enter a valid BETC.
EG04   You must keep the BETC value blank because an imported invoice is matched to either a purchase order or receipt.
EG05   You must enter a valid value for the federal or nonfederal code.
EG06   You must enter a valid trading partner TAS value.
EG07   You must enter the required trading partner TAS for suppliers when the federal or nonfederal code is either Federal or General Fund.
EG08   You can't enter the trading partner TAS and BETC unless the federal or nonfederal code is Federal or General Fund.
EG09   You must enter a valid trading partner BETC.
EG10   You must enter the trading partner BETC for suppliers when the federal or nonfederal code is either Federal or General Fund.
EG11   You can't enter the trading partner TAS and BETC unless the federal or nonfederal code is Federal or General Fund.
EG12   You must enter a valid agency location code.
EG13   You must enter the agency location code.
EG14   You can't enter an agency location code for this transaction.
EG15   You must enter Y, N, or blank in the Data Act Reporting field.
EG16   You must select a value for the data act award type when the data act reportable indicator is enabled.
EG17   You must enter a valid data act award type value.
EG18   You must enter the procurement instrument identifier for procurement awards.
EG19   You can't enter a procurement instrument identifier for financial assistance awards.
EG20   You can't enter the parent award for financial assistance awards.
EG21   You can't enter the FAIN for procurement awards.
EG22   You must enter either FAIN or URI for financial assistance awards.
EG23   You must enter either FAIN or URI but not both at the same time.
EG24   You can't enter the URI for procurement awards.
 
** Batches listed under Unbalanced Batches** weren't imported.
 
 
 
 
                                                    ***** End of Report ********
```

From this file I want to get 2 separate blocks, the first block should contain the following:

```
                                                         Total   Total   Total Unbalanced Unbalanced       Flex    Nonflex
Journal Entry Source Name    Group ID           Status    Lines Batches Headers    Batches    Headers     Errors     Errors
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Manual                                    90005 Error         1       1       1          1          1          0          0
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       *** TOTALS ***                                         1       1       1          1          1          0          0
```

and the second block should be:

```
=================================================   Unbalanced Journal Entries**   =================================================
 
 
Error                                                                            Total
Code  Journal Entry Name                    Batch Name                           Lines Period Name    Total Debits    Total Credits
----- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ----- ----------- ---------------- ----------------
EU02   Adjustment SEM980701STA             Importación de asientos SOAPUI 11102     1 Oct-22              1,300.00             0.00
```

Finally, I want to obtain the error description. In this case, when obtaining EU02, I must obtain the description of the list:

EU02   The journal entry is unbalanced and suspense posting isn't allowed in the ledger.

I have been testing with the query:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_filecontent,
                'Journal Entry Source Name    Group ID           Status    Lines Batches Headers    Batches    Headers     Errors     Errors
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------[^,]+*** TOTALS ***') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" into v_resume
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Tell us what the algorithm is.  For example, you could read up to a line that contains the string `*** TOTALS ***` to get the first block.  But I don't know if you want to use that as your delimiter or read a fixed number of lines or read up to the `======` or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your full text as above (stored it in the CLOB column of a table A_TBL)...
You can try it like this:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    FullText    VarChar2(32767);
    txt_1       VarChar2(4000);
    txt_2       VarChar2(4000);
    txt_errs    VarChar2(4000);
    errs        VarChar2(4000);
    err_list    VarChar2(4000) := '';
    old_err_list    VarChar2(4000) := '';
    errors      VarChar2(4000) := '';
    --
    s1_start    Number(5);
    s1_end      Number(5);
    s2_start    Number(5);
    s2_end      Number(5);
    err_start   Number(5);
    err_end     Number(5);
    err_codes_start   Number(5);
    --
    counter   Number(2) := 0;
--
Begin
    Select TXT Into FullText From A_TBL Where A1G = 123;
    --
    s1_start := InStr(FullText, 'Page:               1', 1, 1) + Length('Page:               1');
    s1_end := InStr(FullText, '=======================================================   Batches Created', 1, 1) - 1;
    txt_1 := SubStr(FullText, s1_start, s1_end - s1_start);
    
    --
    s2_start := InStr(FullText, 'Unbalanced Journal Entries**   =================================================', 1, 1) + 88;
    s2_end := InStr(FullText, '=========================================================   Error Lines', 1, 1) - 1;
    txt_2 := SubStr(FullText, s2_start, s2_end - s2_start);
    
    --
    err_start := InStr(FullText, 'Unbalanced Journal Error Codes', 1, 1);
    err_end := InStr(FullText, 'Flexfield Error Codes', 1, 1) - 1;
    txt_errs := SubStr(FullText, err_start, err_end - err_start);

    --
    err_codes_start := InStr(txt_2, Chr(10), 1, 3) + 1;
    errs := SubStr(txt_2, err_codes_start);

    For i In 1..6 Loop
       If Length(errs) > 4 Then
            err_list := err_list || SubStr(errs, 1, 4) || ';';
            errs := SubStr(errs, InStr(errs, Chr(10), 1, 1) + 1);
        Else
            EXIT;
        End If;
    End Loop;

    While Length(err_list) > 4 Loop
        counter := counter + 1;
        
        If counter = 1 Then
            errors := errors || SubStr(txt_errs, InStr(txt_errs, SubStr(err_list, 1, 4)), InStr(txt_errs, Chr(10), InStr(txt_errs, SubStr(err_list, 1, 4)), 1) - InStr(txt_errs, SubStr(err_list, 1, 4))) || Chr(10);
        else
            errors := errors || SubStr(txt_errs, InStr(txt_errs, SubStr(err_list, 1, 4)), InStr(txt_errs, Chr(10), InStr(txt_errs, SubStr(old_err_list, 1, 4)), 1) - InStr(txt_errs, SubStr(old_err_list, 1, 4))) || Chr(10);
        End If;
        old_err_list := err_list;
        err_list := REPLACE(err_list, SubStr(err_list, 1, 5), '');
    End Loop;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('S e c t i o n   1 ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(txt_1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('S e c t i o n   2 ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(txt_2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('E r r o r s ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(errors);
End;
/*
    R e s u l t :

S e c t i o n   1 

                                                          Total   Total   Total Unbalanced Unbalanced       Flex    Nonflex
Journal Entry Source Name    Group ID           Status    Lines Batches Headers    Batches    Headers     Errors     Errors
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Manual                                    90005 Error         1       1       1          1          1          0          0
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       *** TOTALS ***                                         1       1       1          1          1          0          0
 
S e c t i o n   2 
Error                                                                            Total
Code  Journal Entry Name                    Batch Name                           Lines Period Name    Total Debits    Total Credits
----- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ----- ----------- ---------------- ----------------
EU02   Adjustment SEM980701STA             Importación de asientos SOAPUI 11102     1 Oct-22              1,300.00             0.00
  
 
E r r o r s 
EU02   The journal entry is unbalanced and suspense posting isn't allowed in the ledger.
*/
```

For Loop generates the list of error codes from section 2 and While Loop gets the error texts from 'Unbalanced Journal Error Codes' part of your full text. I have tryed it with two error codes in section 2, and it works.
With Section 2 like here:

```sql
/*
S e c t i o n   2 
Error                                                                            Total
Code  Journal Entry Name                    Batch Name                           Lines Period Name    Total Debits    Total Credits
----- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ----- ----------- ---------------- ----------------
EU02   Adjustment SEM980701STA             Importación de asientos SOAPUI 11102     1 Oct-22              1,300.00             0.00
EU03   xxxxxx
*/
```

The Errors should be:

```sql
/* 
E r r o r s 
EU02   The journal entry is unbalanced and suspense posting isn't allowed in the ledger.
EU03   The encumbrance journal entry is unbalanced and the Reserve for Encumbrance accoun
*/
```

You will, probably, need to do some additional adjustments to get it work with your file changing content.
Regards...

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will adapt what is necessary, your answer was very useful :)